# How do you import a dataframe with an array as it's value into a sparse tensor?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have a pandas dataframe which contains an array of strings which I'm trying to import into a sparse tensor but no matter what I try, I end up with a **`ValueError: too many values to unpack`** error.

**Data Frame**

```
                                                  tags  
0    [cup, lighting, porcelain, saucer, cafeteria, ...  
2    [carrot, root, vegetable, produce, cucumber, f...
```

**Code**

Without sharing all of my code, I'm using the `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` and importing the tags into a column that's defined as:

```
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('tags', hash_bucket_size=5000)
```

The estimator is build this way (where `df` is my pandas dataframe):

```
statuses = df.pop('status')

tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
  x=df,
  y=statuses,
  batch_size=100,
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=False,
  num_threads=5,
  target_column='status')
```

And my code fails when I call `fit()` on my estimator.

**Stack Trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 84, in <module>
    estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn(df_train, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True), steps=500)
  File "/Users/user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 289, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 455, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/Users/user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 953, in _train_model
    features, labels = input_fn()
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Can you share a stack trace of the error you're seeing?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I included it above.

Comment: There must be a bug in how you create the input_fn before passing it to fit().  The pandas_input_fn() call you quoted can't be right, because "x=df, y=df['status']" would trigger this error: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/pandas_io.py#L81

Comment: @DavidSoergel You're right that that error was triggered – I've updated the code sample above to reflect the change I made to address that. However, that's still the issue I get. If I use a string instead of an array for tags, it works no problem, but as soon as the tags is an array of strings, I get that error.